# Images not displaying and not loading html src

Tags: html, css, image

I have just uploaded two images to my website in "images" folder. I'm trying to display them using `img` tag -but all I'm getting is broken tag. So I have tried to open the image in a new tab using it's URL. But the URL kept on loading forward and backward and finally stopped displaying a blank page. Please help

```html
<img src="images/guestbook4.jpg" width="129" height="63" name="MyImage5">
```

[Here's the URL to the image I've uploaded](https://phatpig.com/images/guestbook5.jpg)
[image: Snapshot of website files where the image is uploaded]

Comment: share your markup(html)?

Comment: Where is the html ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses. Here's my code <img src="images/guestbook4.jpg" width="129" height="63" name="MyImage5">

Answer (score 1):

your `image` directory is in the root. so you can access to it from the root or from the current path.

when you set image src to `example/avatar.png`, that means, example folder exist in current path. so the request will send to example directory in current path. if your code file not be in the same directory that example directory exist in, this problem occur.

if you use `/example/avatar.png`, that means, example folder exist in root. so the request will send to example directory in root path.

Comment: Images folder and the code I'm running are in the same directory. The problem is strange. Sometimes images are getting displayed and sometimes broken tag

Comment: @vambaycolony maybe it's because of the cache. did you try to clear cache?